# Tree: toggle <li> but link <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have something like this:
[image]
I need to toggle the folders and open the pdfs.
The folders have the class click.
This is my test-code. You will notice, that if i click on a pdf it will hide the folder (    e.preventDefault()).
Again: **I need to toggle the folders and open the pdfs?**
How can I achieve this?

```
$("div.xxx ul li.click").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    if($(this).hasClass('active')) {
        $(this).removeClass('active').children("ul").hide();
    }else {
        $(this).addClass('active').children("ul").show();
    }
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="xxx">
<ul>
    <li class="icon-pdf">
        <a href="xx.pdf">20130315151327_Kaufvertrag_.pdf</a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon-pdf">
        <a href="xxx">Entwurf_Kaufvertrag.pdf</a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon-folder folder click">
        <a href="Array">Ordner</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="icon-pdf">
and so on...
```

Comment: Use JQuery toggle function .. :) Sounds just funny.. "I need to toggle the folders and open the pdfs" and the answer is toggle function..

Comment: looks fine.. but can be cleanup as http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/QK38b/1/

Comment: would it be possible to modify the html output through your backend script, or you don't have control over that? If it's possible see my answer below, I think it's one of the simplest solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to your existing script, you could just prevent default on the anchors which are direct children of the folders:

```
$('.icon-folder > a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

The other anchor elements should work as usual still as they're not direct children of `.icon-folder`.

Comment: sure! :)
that works but I'm not sure if this is a good solution.

Comment: Alternatively, remove the anchors for the folders and use CSS `cursor:pointer` to show the hand cursor on hover over the `<li>` folder elements. Then you won't need the script above at all :)

Comment: In my case this seems to be the only solution that works. I tried out the other ideas but none worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$("div.xxx").find('a').click(function(){
    e.stopPropagation();
}).find('li.click').click(function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active').find("ul").toggle();
});
```

just toggle the className `.active` on the clicking `li.click` and find the ul inside it and `.toggle()` it too.

---

As per your latest comment:

*but the problem is still the  which will close the `<li>` instead of link the href.*

```
$("div.xxx").find('a').click(function(){
    e.stopPropagation();
// stop the click event on anchor to bubble up to the li.
```

Comment: this works but the problem is still the <a> which will close the <li> instead of link the href

Answer (score 0):

Giving the click class to the `<li>` element and triggering the click on it will make the event work on all of its children.

I assume you are generating the folders and the pdf's links serverside, a simple solution would be to give the `<a>` element the click class instead when it's a folder, and leave it as normal when it's a pdf.

Also using the jQuery's function `toggle()` as suggested in the comments would be advisable.

---

So Basically, your html should look like this (Pay attention to the `Ordner` link):

```
<div class="xxx">
<ul>
    <li class="icon-pdf">
        <a href="xx.pdf">20130315151327_Kaufvertrag_.pdf</a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon-pdf">
        <a href="xxx">Entwurf_Kaufvertrag.pdf</a>
    </li>
    <li class="icon-folder folder">
        <a href="Array" class="click">Ordner</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="icon-pdf">
```

And your jQuery something like this:

```
$('.click').click(function(){
  $(this).next().toggle(); // I guess the <ul> is always after the <a>
});
```

Comment: thx for your time! I rebuilt the html and gave it a try with your toggle-solution. Sadly it din't work as expected.

Comment: What failed? I tested personally and it worked, perhaps I can still help you out.

Comment: If I first $("div.xxx ul li ul").hide(); by click on first "ordner" your script just goes to url/array. 
If I don't hide it first, the first "ordner" and the third goes to /array rest is ok.

Answer (score 0):

you just need to  use `slideToggle`

```
 $("div.xxx ").click(function(e) {
     $(this).find('ul li').slideToggle('slow');  
 });
```

*Note: if adding of `active` class  was for sliding the elements, then this code will hold good.*

**LIVE DEMO:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/BxL2B/3/

Keep It Simple Silly

Happy Coding :)

Comment: this works but the problem is still the <a> which will close the <li> instead of link the href.

Comment: @ava: i have update the code to toggle only when clicked over the div, when clicked over the individual `li`, it will navigate.